# What does ‘vor sich hertreiben’ really mean?

Tags: german-to-english

The expression *vor sich hertreiben* occurs twice in the *Süddeutsche Zeitung* article "[Donald Trump treibt Hillary Clinton vor sich her](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/politik/us-praesidentschaftswahl-donald-trump-treibt-hillary-clinton-vor-sich-her-1.3170218)". In the name of the article itself and at the end of the following paragraph:

> Eine simple Formel wie "Nach [Terror]Anschlägen steigt Trumps Popularität" gibt es nicht: Seine Reaktion auf den Anschlag auf den Gay-Club in Orlando führte zu einem Knick in den Umfragen - doch er hat sich wieder herangekämpft. In den Umfragen wird Clinton etwas mehr Expertise in der Terrorbekämpfung zugewiesen, aber die regelmäßigen Nachrichten über Anschläge sorgen für Unsicherheit. **Dass es dem Republikaner Trump gelingt, momentan Clinton *vor sich herzutreiben*, hat dabei mehrere Gründe**.

I could find two translations of the expression. In [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=vor%20sich%20hertreiben):

> etw. schreiend vor sich hertreiben = to whoop sth. *[to drive cattle etc. with whooping cries]*

In [Leo's Dictionary](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=vor%20sich%20hertreiben&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on&pos=0):

> etw. vor etw. hertreiben = to drive sth. in front of sth. *[tech.]*

To me it's not particularly meaningful that Trump drives Clinton in front of himself. So, what does the expression *vor sich hertreiben* mean?

Comment: Think of a battue (germ. *Treibjagd*): Trump drives Clinton into a trap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dict.cc translation is the one you want. Originally it is used for animals (cattle, horses, etc.). In a metaphorical sense it can have several meanings, for example

> to control/steer somebody at will
>   to hunt/scare somebody
>   to be one step ahead of/too quick for somebody

Probably the last translation is the one that is meant here. The article states that Clinton is forced to react and defend herself all the time instead of having time to put Trump in a position where he has to defend himself.

Comment: Vor jemandem zu sein, den man vor sich hertreibt, passt aber nicht zusammen. Bei der Treibjagd versucht das Wild auch zur Seite auszubüchsen und der Vorteil der Jäger besteht nicht darin, schneller zu sein, sondern langsam sein zu können, weil man die Zick-Zack-Bewegung des Wilds nicht mitmachen muss und so den längeren Atem zu haben.

Comment: @userunknown Ich meinte das auch eher in dem Sinne von *einen Schritt voraus zu sein* und natürlich nicht lokal. Habe die Antwort entsprechend ergänzt.

Answer (score 2):

It means having the initiative on s.b., making him react to your moves.

Picture an army steadily advancing while the opposing army has to move backwards and doesn't get an opportunity to make a stand.

Answer (score 1):

The comment to *vor sich hertreiben* at LEO http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=1247107&idForum=1&lang=de&lp=ende explains is quite well. The original "Wie Konzerne Staaten vor sich hertreiben" was translated to

> How corporations push countries around
> ... run countries
> ... pull their strings
> ... dictate ...

which is along the lines of what @ThorstenDittmar proposed in his answer.